# Why is my scrapy script missing?

Tags: python, scrapy

It's probably something basic, but I couldn't find any recent (non-deprecated) examples. Given the following code

```
#This is the tutorial project for scrapy

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class DmozItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    desc = Field()

from scrapy.spider import Spider

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"

    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/") [-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

I get this error message

```
jacob@Harold ~/Desktop/Scrapy_Projects/tutorial $ scrapy list
jacob@Harold ~/Desktop/Scrapy_Projects/tutorial $ scrapy crawl dmoz
2014-02-21 15:24:37-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: tutorial)
2014-02-21 15:24:37-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
2014-02-21 15:24:37-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-02-21 15:24:37-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-02-21 15:24:37-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 132, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 97, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 139, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 43, in run
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 43, in create
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: %s" % spider_name)
KeyError: 'Spider not found: dmoz'
```

I figure it's probably something really basic, and I tried searching for examples I could look through to see what it is, but I didn't find any that I thought were recent enough.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What did you already try?
Also, post some code on here, dont link us outside. Describe how you understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the following code comes in a python file called items.py(All these steps should be followed after you use the startproject command as mentioned by hwatkins)

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class DmozItem(Item):
        title = Field()
        link = Field()
        desc = Field()
```

The rest of the code that follows is from the `spider.py` file which should be created inside the spiders folder in your project.

Also you will need to import `DmozItem` as `from dmoz.items import DmozItem` in your spider if you want to use it in the spider.

I suggest you follow the tutorial once again carefully

Comment: Ya, I missed the part about having the sections split into different files. I did read through the tutorial a few times, but I evidently missed that part. Thank you, and sorry it was such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions:

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

This will create the project, then save your script in a file named `dmoz_spider.py` under the `tutorial/spiders` directory

I just tried it with your script and it worked ok.